# Consulta Access con fechas tipo DateTimePicker en C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Buenas. Tengo un problema con mi codigo. No entiende las variables para una consulta entre fechas `DateTimePicker`.

Este es mi código.

```
public DataTable selcfecharegitro()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection cone = new OleDbConnection(cc.conaccess);
        DateTime desde = Convert.ToDateTime(new datosform().dtpdesde);
        DateTime hasta = Convert.ToDateTime(new datosform().dtphasta);
        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM Registro where Fecha_uso between = '" + desde + "' and '" + hasta + "' ", cone);

        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return dt;
    }
```

y me muestra este error a la hora que busco el rango de fechas.

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: solo como nota, si no usas consultas parametrizadas access usa como separador en las fechas el simbolo #

Comment: `DateTime desde = new datosform().dtpdesde.Value;
DateTime hasta = new datosform().dtphasta.Value;
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM Registro where Fecha_uso between @desde and @hasta", cone);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde",desde);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta",hasta);
da.Fill(ds);`

Comment: en este caso donde pondria el msimbolo??

Answer (score 2):

Esos problemas siempre suelen surgir por no utilizar **Consultas parametrizadas**, que solucionan este tipo de problemas,asi como los de [Inyeccion SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Por otro lado, para obtener el valor seleccionado en un `DateTimePicker`, debes acceder a la propiedad `Value`, que devuelve un `DateTime`.

Intenta este código:

```
...
DateTime desde = new datosform().dtpdesde.Value;
DateTime hasta = new datosform().dtphasta.Value;
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM Registro where Fecha_uso between @desde and @hasta", cone);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde",desde);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta",hasta);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: me muestra el mismo error

Comment: Mira la respuesta editada. Fijate en como se crean los valores `desde`y `hasta`

Comment: El DateTimePicker del formulario

Comment: Perdon, puse base de datos sql y es access

Comment: @Pikoh, ¿el signo `=` no generaría error?

Comment: @Mauricio por supuesto que si. Es lo que pasa por copiar parte del código del OP. Editado,gracias :)

Comment: Puedes corregir el query, esta usando access y para fechas utiliza como separador #. ver https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762

Comment: @gbianchi utilizando una consulta parametrizada, en ningun caso debería  utilizarse separador. Aunque no estoy muy acostumbrado a usar access, pero dudo que los separadores del tipo `#`sean necesarios si no cometes el error de componer la query concatenando strings